# Material UI Theme

Tags: android-studio, material-ui, android-studio-3.0

When I install the Material UI theme that is compatible with my android studio version. It automatically changes the language of the android studio. Some of the words are in English the others are in another language. I have tried finding the language settings but as far as I know, Android Studio IntelliJ does not have different language options.

Comment: Are you using custom fonts on your PC?

Comment: @MbuodileObiosio, No I am not using custom fonts on my PC